# Moving repo from Bitbucket to existing repo in GitHub

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Hi I am very new to coding and git and need some help. I am working on a small project where the customer has decided to move depository from Bitbucket to GitHub. They have moved the code without letting me know. What I need to do is to disconnect my project from Bitbucket, connect it to the existing GitHub repository and commit my latest changes to GitHub. It is a small project and I am using Visual Studio Code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the console in your project root and type:

```
$ git remote set-url origin <newGitHubURL>
```

The URL should be something like: https://github.com/username/projectname.git